# How to find common entries in a list, based off of one variable in the object?

Tags: java, list, set

I have a class

```
public class A{
   private String x;
   private String y;
   private String z;
}
```

I have multiple lists `List<List<A>>` and need to find the common entries in all of the lists. The entries are the same if one object's x == another object's x.

If I were checking for equality of objects, I could have just converted the lists into sets and used `retainAll()`. But how do I do this when y and z could be different, by x has to be the same.

Comment: Not sure if I get you right, but seems like you just need to override equals and hashcode for your class A, so it returns true only if this.x == x

Comment: Construct a `Map<String, List<A>>`.  Iterate over all the `A`s in your list of lists, and add each one to the `Map` value associated with the `A`'s member `x`.  When you're done, your map will have one entry for each distinct `x` among all the `A`'s, and that entry will have as its value a List of all the `A`'s with that `x`.

Comment: And if you really mean that you want to match based on object identity (`==`) rather than equality (`equals()`), then choose `IdentityHashMap` as your map implementation.

Comment: What you are expecting as output? is it List<A> having object A.x same values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class, write a function that gives you back your X value....

```
public class A {
    private String x;
    private String y;
    private String z;
    ...
    public String getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

... then iterate over the list-of-lists (O(n^2)) and sort them according to their common X values.

```
public Map<String, List<A>> findCommonEntries(List<List<A>> aListList) {
    Map<String, List<A>> aMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (List<A> aList : aListList) {
        for (A a : aList) {
            if (!aMap.containsKey(a.getX()))
                aMap.put(a.getX(), new ArrayList<>());

            aMap.get(a.getX()).add(a);
        }
    }
}
```

You should, at the end of this, have a map of all strings stored anywhere in an X to a list of all A's containing that X.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is a good use-case for Java8 streams, where you can apply different collectors to accumulate the elements of a stream. The code below will perform the requested transformation:

```
Map<String, List<A>> collect = lists.stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getX));
```

This API definitely gains in readability, but might also provide good performance as this Collector is provided by the JDK.

You can find a working example here: https://gist.github.com/sermojohn/e8828288172d5c9e85046c4b25a7d425

Answer (score 0):

You can flat all lists into one single list, group all elements with `x` field and then leave keys that present in all lists (by values size):

```
public static Set<String> getCommonEntries(List<List<A>> lists) {
    Map<String, List<A>> map = lists.stream()
                                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getX));
    map.values().removeIf(l -> l.size() != lists.size());
    return map.keySet();
}
```